# How to Diagnose a Flashing Red Light on Dell PowerEdge 1950

Tags: windows-server-2003

The server has a flashing red light in the back of it while all the HDD seem to be working fine. How can I run a diagnostics test to figure out what the flashing light means? This is windows Server 2003 on a  Dell PowerEdge 1950.

[Flashing Light Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRgj2.jpg)

P.S. I realize this is completely outdated and it will be replaced soon, but for now it is running a required application of ours so please don't scold too much (I'm only in charge of fixing it =))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user's manual for the 1950 calls this the system status indicator light but doesn't provide any further details. Is the LCD on the front panel displaying an error code, perhaps. Error codes are listed in the manual so maybe that will help.

From a visual inspection, do both power supplies (if you have dual supplies) appear to be working? Any screeching noises or rubbing sounds? Can you hear the fans spinning inside the chassis? Are there any PCI or PCIe cards plugged into backplane? Does removing them and rebooting clear the light? While booting, are there any error messages showing that you can't account for?

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a new server and copy over the HDD's diagnostics only do so much and I would be surprised if it lasts another month.

From a pentesting point of view it takes about 30 seconds to breach a windows server 2003 box via various vulnerabilities.

You are going to pay more to fix it then to get a new server.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion however you did not address my question. If you are not going to stay on topic I'd request you stay off my post.

Comment: The part in question was much cheaper than a new server, and it is still running